# Update core data database based on criteria using NSBatchUpdate function

Tags: swift, database, core-data, nsbatchupdaterequest

I couldn't find anywhere for the answer. I have a database implemented with simple core data and an entity filled with data. Every time I open the app, I need to go through all database and one column contains a date. If the date is already passed (compared to today) I need to add one year to it.

After googling I found that `NSBatchUpdate` could help here. But how to go through all records in the database and update date value based on criteria?

Thanks in advance for support.